Slow performance while loading data of a view
I got a view "project_sum" in my mariaDB database. This view got 4 problematic columns, of which each calulates the sum of accounting_records. Each of them sums up values of up to 200 accounting_records.
In the end the view gets about 5.000 rows in total. So it have to calculate 5.000x4 sums for around 5.000x200 accounting_record values.
This is the query of the view:
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS project_sum;

CREATE VIEW project_sum AS
SELECT
    project_id,
    SUM(CASE
                WHEN planned_actual_indicator = 'planned' AND datev_type = 'incoming'
                THEN (value_in_euro)
                ELSE 0
                END
        ) AS 'sum_incoming_planned',
    SUM(CASE
                WHEN planned_actual_indicator = 'actual' AND datev_type = 'incoming'
                THEN (value_in_euro)
                ELSE 0
                END
        ) AS 'sum_incoming_actual',
    SUM(CASE
                WHEN planned_actual_indicator = 'planned' AND datev_type = 'outgoing'
                THEN (value_in_euro)
                ELSE 0
                END
        ) AS 'sum_outgoing_planned',
    SUM(CASE
                WHEN planned_actual_indicator = 'actual' AND datev_type = 'outgoing'
                THEN (value_in_euro)
                ELSE 0
                END
        ) AS 'sum_outgoing_actual'
FROM accounting_record USE INDEX (is_initial)
WHERE accounting_record.is_initial = false
GROUP BY project_id;

Unfortunately there is a need for the sums to be always up to date, when opening the view. There is a zero tolerance policy for wrong values, since it is about money.
Therefore we have to calculate the sums on-the-fly and can't store them pre-calculated in a database table. This makes loading the page very slow and the loading performance very bad.
One idea I had was to update pre-calculated sums everytime a new accounting_record will be pushed, but then we thought about racing conditions, which may eventually causing one summation missing the value of another record, which was added at the same time.
We have already indexed the keys of the records we sum up: is_initial, planned_actual_indicator and even datev_type and project_id. But that also didn't help much. Is there any way to improve this query so that the performance is better?

Could you edit your question and share the table definition and indexes, and the result from explain for your query ?

To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please read this, then [edit] your question.

do show example queries of how you use the view, and explain and show create table output for accounting_record and any other table used in the queries

you don't say exactly how slow it is, or how fast you need it to be.  it seems likely with more information that it can be sped up at least some, but if that isn't adequate, you certainly can reliably keep the sums in a separate table and keep them up to date with update/insert/delete triggers on accounting_record

What percentage of the table has is_initial = FALSE?

You haven’t told us anything useful about your table structure or indexes so this is guesswork.
Get rid of USE INDEX. Not even Monty Widenius uses that.
Create a compound covering index…
ALTER TABLE accounting_record 
  ADD INDEX viewcover 
            ( is_initial, project_id, 
              planned_actual_indicator, datev_type, 
              value_in_euro)

It should be possible to generate your result set with a sequential index range scan on this index. That will save a mess of IO and a temp table sort step, which should help.
Notice, though, that the query in this view necessarily must process a very large fraction of the rows in your table. There isn’t any weird SQL voodoo that makes that faster than O(n) . So you’d be wise to temper your users’ expectations.
